# Files added to MockFileSystem don't have Exists = true when returned from FileInfo.FromFileName()

Tags: unit-testing, moq, c#-7.0

Also found on...
https://github.com/System-IO-Abstractions/System.IO.Abstractions/issues/393

(But there's a wider audience here)

In a test I have the following:

```
var testSettings = new ApplicationSettings() { DefaultLedgerFilename = testLedgerFilename };

//Add the byte array as file data
var fileData = new MockFileData(testSettings); //I added an overload PR #389

//Create a file system with the fake data as a "file"
var fileSystem = new MockFileSystem(new Dictionary<string, MockFileData>
{
{ AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"MoneyTrackerConfig.config", fileData }
});
```

In the codebase I have the following:

```
var tempFile = _fileSystem.FileInfo.FromFileName(_path);
if (tempFile.Exists && (tempFile.Length > 0))
{
    ...
```

The problem is when I run the test 'tempFile.Exists' returns 'false'. Even if I create the file on the drive it returns 'false'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Found the issue.
After a day of debugging (that included digging into and debugging the System.IO.Abstractions source) I realized that I missed a backslash.

Yup, pure user error. Note the line above

```
{ AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"MoneyTrackerConfig.config", fileData }
```

... it should be ...

```
{ AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+@"\MoneyTrackerConfig.config", fileData }
```

Sorry for anyone that took this seriously. I feel ridiculous.